# Big Mysql table optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a table that I use to cache google translate API answers.
Table structure is
[image: db structure]

Now it has more that 1million rows with 35000 distinct values in `group` field.
The only query type I use is:

```
SELECT `orig_string`, `group`, `translated` FROM `Google_translate_cache` WHERE 
    (`group` = "?" AND
        ((`orig_string` = "?") 
     OR (`orig_string` = "?") 
     OR (`orig_string` = "?") ....
```

Now every query take more then 2 seconds.

I have tried to change the query to `UNION` one, but the result was the same.

In addition I tried to partition table like this -

```
ALTER TABLE `Google_translate_cache`
    PARTITION BY KEY(`orig_string`)
    PARTITIONS 26;
```

But this also was not successful.

Any suggestion to speed up it?

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot - `orig_string` and `group` are indexes.

Comment: Ah, you mean they are underlined. Of course. It is so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't think the partitioning of the table on the "orig_string" is really what you want.  Instead, an compound index on the (group, orig_string) the help optimize where WHERE clause qualifier.  Now, with the group column -- really 255 capacity? Is that large really required when the original string being tested maxes out at 100?  Having an index of too much might cause a bit of a lag, but cant definitively say with lack of knowledge of actual content.

I would start with the compound index and not partition in the way indicated.